# Numpy installation AWS EC2 Error

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I tried easy install and pip to install numpy on an EC2 micro instance.   Didn't work.

I get:

> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

I tried virtualenv too, same story.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

You probably don't have the development packages installed.

Amazon Linux run:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Ubuntu run:

```
sudo apt-get install packaging-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple testing, ssh into your instance

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo pip install numpy
```

then go get yourself a coffee. Installed in about 3.5 mins.